How to insert (contents of) one .dox file into another?
Say I have two additional documentation files, main.dox and subsection.dox. I would like to include the contents of subsection.dox into main.dox. Can this be done with doxygen?
I do not want it as a subpage. I want the contents just directly imported.
\input seems to only work with source files, and similarly I couldn't achieve this with \htmlinput nor \verbinput.

Which version of doxygen did you use? Did you try \input{doc} subsection.dox?

@albert I'm on doxygen 1.9.7 (a2f34e1ed90f83713dc347b5134920f32c455d46)
I just tried your suggestion, it didn't work. It renders it as text, as if it doesn't recognize the command.

Doxygen 1.9.7 is a bit older (May 18,2023), the current version is doxygen 1.12.0 maybe here \includedoc subsection.dox  works. Do you get any warnings? Otherwise please add a small full example showing the problem, including your settings used (i.e. the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile)

Just out of curiosity, what is the use-case? Maybe there is another way to achieve what you want.
